# Combining two leaflet plugins

Tags: leaflet

I am new to leaflet (but I used leaflet with R) and javascript. I have discovered two great leaflet plugins, Leaflet.Elevation and leaflet-gpx. I managed to make them work individually, but I was wondering if they could be both combined in one map. I tried but I failed miserably. Maybe I could use Leaflet.Sync but I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction (if possible).

here is what I have so far. The first big part of the code is working, it the last past part of the code (starting at var el = L.control.elevation();) that I can't make work

```
<head>
<title>leaflet-gpx demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.5/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/leaflet.elevation-0.0.4.css" />

<style type="text/css">
  body { width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto; }
  .gpx { border: 5px #aaa solid; border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #ccc;
    width: 1100px; height: 550px;, margin: 0; }
  .gpx header { padding: 0.5em; }
  .gpx h4 { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-weight: bold; }
   .gpx .start { font-size: smaller; color: #444; }
  .gpx .map { border: 1px #888 solid; border-left: none; border-right: none;
    width: 1100px; height: 430px; margin: 0; }
  .gpx footer { background: #f0f0f0; padding: 0.5em; }
  .gpx ul.info { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: smaller;}
  .gpx ul.info li { color: #666; padding: 2px; display: inline; }
  .gpx ul.info li span { color: black; }
</style>
</head>


<body>
```

```
  <article>
    <div class="map" id="demo-map"></div>
  </article>

  <footer>
    <ul class="info">
      <li>Distance:&nbsp;<span class="distance"></span>&nbsp;meter</li>
      &mdash; <li>Duration:&nbsp;<span class="duration"></span></li>
<!--      &mdash; <li>Pace:&nbsp;<span class="pace"></span>/meter</li> -->
 <!--     &mdash; <li>Avg&nbsp;HR:&nbsp;<span class="avghr"></span>&nbsp;bpm</li> -->
      &mdash; <li>Elevation:&nbsp;+<span class="elevation-gain"></span>&nbsp;meter,
        -<span class="elevation-loss"></span>&nbsp;meter
        (net:&nbsp;<span class="elevation-net"></span>&nbsp;meter)</li>
       &mdash;  Inspired by <a href="https://github.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx">leaflet-gpx</a>.<br>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</section>

<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx/master/gpx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/leaflet.elevation-0.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
  function display_gpx(elt) {
    if (!elt) return;

    var url = elt.getAttribute('data-gpx-source');
    var mapid = elt.getAttribute('data-map-target');
    if (!url || !mapid) return;

    function _t(t) { return elt.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; }
    function _c(c) { return elt.getElementsByClassName(c)[0]; }

    var map = L.map(mapid);
    L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
      attribution: 'iles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
    }).addTo(map);


    new L.GPX("gpsfile.gpx", {
      async: true,
      marker_options: {
            startIconUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-icon-start.png',
            endIconUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-icon-end.png',
            shadowUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-shadow.png'
      },
    }).on('loaded', function(e) {
      var gpx = e.target;
      map.fitBounds(gpx.getBounds());

      _t('h3').textContent = gpx.get_name();
      _c('start').textContent = gpx.get_start_time().toDateString() + ', '
        + gpx.get_start_time().toLocaleTimeString();
      _c('end').textContent = gpx.get_end_time().toDateString() + ', '
        + gpx.get_end_time().toLocaleTimeString();
      _c('distance').textContent = gpx.get_distance().toFixed(2);
      _c('duration').textContent = gpx.get_duration_string(gpx.get_moving_time());
<!--      _c('pace').textContent     = gpx.get_duration_string(gpx.get_moving_pace(), true); -->
<!--      _c('avghr').textContent    = gpx.get_average_hr(); -->
      _c('elevation-gain').textContent = (gpx.get_elevation_gain()).toFixed(0);
      _c('elevation-loss').textContent = (gpx.get_elevation_loss()).toFixed(0);
      _c('elevation-net').textContent  = (gpx.get_elevation_gain()
      - gpx.get_elevation_loss()).toFixed(0);
    }).addTo(map);
  }

  display_gpx(document.getElementById('demo'));

    var el = L.control.elevation();
    el.addTo(map);
    var g=new L.GPX("gpsfile.gpx", {
        async: true,
         marker_options: {
            startIconUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-icon-start.png',
            endIconUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-icon-end.png',
            shadowUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-shadow.png'
          }
    });
    g.on('loaded', function(e) {
            map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    });
    g.on("addline",function(e){
        el.addData(e.line);
    });
    g.addTo(map);


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: A code sample showing what you have tried would be a useful start. The question is too vague as it stands. In theory, there is no reason why you can't use multiple Leaflet plugins in the same page.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://github.com/MrMufflon/Leaflet.Elevation#what-is-this), Leaflet.Elevation uses d3, which I don't see included in your code, so that may be part of the problem. Can you look at the console output to see what errors are being thrown?

Comment: to nathansnider, it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined" and the problem is at line "el.addTo(map);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work. The code was fine but only the order needed to be change. Below the chuck of code that needed to be reordered.

```
        var map = L.map(mapid);
    L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
      attribution: 'iles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
    }).addTo(map);

    var el = L.control.elevation();
    el.addTo(map);

            var g=new L.GPX("gpsfile.gpx", {
        async: true,
         marker_options: {
            startIconUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-icon-start.png',
            endIconUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-icon-end.png',
            shadowUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-shadow.png'
          }
    });
    g.on('loaded', function(e) {
            map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    });
    g.on("addline",function(e){
        el.addData(e.line);
    });
    g.addTo(map);

    new L.GPX("gpsfile.gpx", {
      async: true,
      marker_options: {
            startIconUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-icon-start.png',
            endIconUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-icon-end.png',
            shadowUrl: './lib/leaflet-gpx/pin-shadow.png'
      },
    }).on('loaded', function(e) {
      var gpx = e.target;
      map.fitBounds(gpx.getBounds());

      _t('h3').textContent = gpx.get_name();
      _c('start').textContent = gpx.get_start_time().toDateString() + ', '
        + gpx.get_start_time().toLocaleTimeString();
      _c('end').textContent = gpx.get_end_time().toDateString() + ', '
        + gpx.get_end_time().toLocaleTimeString();
      _c('distance').textContent = gpx.get_distance().toFixed(2);
      _c('duration').textContent = gpx.get_duration_string(gpx.get_moving_time());
<!--      _c('pace').textContent     = gpx.get_duration_string(gpx.get_moving_pace(), true); -->
<!--      _c('avghr').textContent    = gpx.get_average_hr(); -->
      _c('elevation-gain').textContent = (gpx.get_elevation_gain()).toFixed(0);
      _c('elevation-loss').textContent = (gpx.get_elevation_loss()).toFixed(0);
      _c('elevation-net').textContent  = (gpx.get_elevation_gain()
      - gpx.get_elevation_loss()).toFixed(0);
    }).addTo(map);
  }

  display_gpx(document.getElementById('demo'));
```